# Programmatically added Bundle Products in Magento don't display correctly in the frontend

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, bundle

First of all: I am using Magento 1.7.0.2.
I have programmed a function, which create a bundled product on the fly and add it to the cart. This product shows in the backend correctly, but in the frontend I'am missing the options, when I want to edit this item from the cart.

I also ran into an issue, that I can't properly add this generated items to the cart. It display me an error:

```
Some of the products below do not have all the required options. Please edit them and configure all the required options.
```

If I open the generated product in the backend and save it there, it display every option in the fronted correctly, but the other error is still appearing.

Here is my code so far:

```
        $storeID = 1;
        $websiteIDs = array(1);
        $cats = array( $this->categoryPresent );
        $productCounter = 0;

        $presentParams['additional'] = 171;  //Product ID
        $presentParams['box'] = 167;  //Product ID
        $presentParams['count'] = 3; //amount of ordered presents

        //Create base bundle with all required attributes
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $p = array(
          'sku_type' => 0,
          'sku' => 'present - ' . strtotime('now'),
          'name' => "Present",
          'description' => 'Present',
          'short_description' => 'Present',
          'type_id' => 'bundle',
          'attribute_set_id' => 9,
          'weight_type' => 0,
          'visibility' => 4,
          'price_type' => 0,
          'price_view' => 0,
          'status' => 1,
          'created_at' => strtotime('now'),
          'category_ids' => $cats,
          'store_id' => $storeID,
          'website_ids' => $websiteIDs,
          'base_price_amount' => '',
          'base_price_base_amount' => 1,
          'base_price_base_unit' => 'St',
          'options_container' => 'container1'
        );
        $product->setData($p);
        $product->setStockData(array(
            'is_in_stock' => 1,
            'qty' => 99999
        ));

        $optionRawData = array();
        $selectionRawData = array();

        //Insert Box
        $productCounter++;
        $optionRawData[] = array(
              'required' => 1,
              'option_id' => '',
              'position' => $productCounter,
              'type' => 'select',
              'title' => 'Box',
              'default_title' => 'Box',
              'delete' => '',
            );
        $selectionRawData[$productCounter-1] = array();
        $selectionRawData[$productCounter-1][] = array(
              'product_id' => $presentParams['box'],
              'selection_qty' => 1,
              'selection_can_change_qty' => 0,
              'position' => $productCounter,
              'is_default' => 1,
              'selection_id' => '',
              'selection_price_type' => 0,
              'selection_price_value' => 0.0,
              'option_id' => '',
              'delete' => ''
        );

        //Insert Additional
        $productCounter++;
        $optionRawData[] = array(
              'required' => 1,
              'option_id' => '',
              'position' => $productCounter,
              'type' => 'select',
              'title' => 'Zubehör',
              'default_title' => 'Zubehör',
              'delete' => '',
            );
        $selectionRawData[$productCounter-1] = array();
        $selectionRawData[$productCounter-1][] = array(
              'product_id' => $presentParams['additional'],
              'selection_qty' => 1,
              'selection_can_change_qty' => 0,
              'position' => $productCounter,
              'is_default' => 1,
              'selection_id' => '',
              'selection_price_type' => 0,
              'selection_price_value' => 0.0,
              'option_id' => '',
              'delete' => ''
        );


        // Set the Bundle Options & Selection Data ; Save the present
        Mage::register('product', $product);
        Mage::register('current_product', $product);
        $product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(false);
        $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
        $product->setCanSaveBundleSelections(true);
        $product->setAffectBundleProductSelections(true);
        $product->setBundleOptionsData($optionRawData);
        $product->setBundleSelectionsData($selectionRawData);
        $product->save();

        //Add Product to cart
        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');

//Try an other way of setting the bundled_option            
/*$option_ids = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($product);
        $selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection($option_ids, $product);
        $bundled_items = array();
        foreach($selectionCollection as $key => $option){
            //$bundled_items[$key] = $option->product_id;
            $bundled_items[$key] = 1;
        }

        $params = array(
            'product' => $product->getId(),
            'related_product' => null,
            'bundle_option' => $bundled_items,
            'qty' => $presentParams['count'],
        );*/

        $cart->addProduct( $product, $presentParams['count']);
        $cart->save();
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

I think, there is just a little piece of code, which is missing. I hope, someone can help to solve this problem.

**UPDATE**

The bundled products are generated in the front-end. So one thing I've found to do then is indexing the new product.
Here is the additional code:

```
//Index new item
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId());
        $stockItem->setForceReindexRequired(true);
        Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->processEntityAction(
            $stockItem,
            Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item::ENTITY,
            Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE
        );

        $product->setForceReindexRequired(true)->setIsChangedCategories(true);
        Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->processEntityAction($product, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE);
```

With this the generated products are correctly listed in the list-view of the responding category. But the contents of the bundle are still missing.

Comment: Added additional Information.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share with you the code I use to create products.
Let's compare it with your and search for errors.

```
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

                $product->setSku($sku);
                $product->setName($product_data['name']);
                $product->setDescription($product_data['description']);
                $product->setShortDescription($product_data['name']);
                $product->setPrice($product_data['price'] * $price_multiplier);
                $product->setTypeId('simple');
                $product->setAttributeSetId(9); // need to look this up
                $product->setCategoryIds(implode(',', $local_categories)); // need to look these up
                $product->setWeight(1.0);
                $product->setTaxClassId(0); // taxable goods
                $product->setVisibility(4); // catalog, search
                $product->setStatus(1); // enabled

                // assign product to the default website
                $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));

                $product->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values'=>array()));

                $first = true;
                foreach ($local_images as $local_image_fname) {
                    $ma = array();
                    if ($first) {
                        $first = false;
                        $ma    = array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail');
                    }
                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($local_image_fname, $ma, false, false);
                }

                $stockData        = $product->getStockData();
                $stockData['qty'] = 1;
                $stockData['is_in_stock'] = 1;
                $stockData['manage_stock'] = 1;
                $stockData['use_config_manage_stock'] = 0;
                $product->setStockData($stockData); 

                $product->save();
                $product_id = $product->getId();
```

I see, you at least do not set TaxClassId.
And weight.

**EDIT**

One more suggestion.
You are adding a bundle products to cart.
Why aren't you setting bundle options?
You only set count.
See nice example how to add bundle product to cart programatically:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programatically-add-bundle-product-to-cart-n-magento/

```
$params = array(
    'product' => 164,
    'related_product' => null,
    'bundle_option' => array(
        21 => 58,
        20 => 55,
        11 => 28,
        12 => array(
            0 => 31,
        ),
        13 => array(
            0 => 32,
            1 => 35,
        ),
    ),
    'options' => array(
        3 => 'olaaaaaaaa',
    ),
    'qty' => 2,
);
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
$product->load(164);
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
$message = $this->__('Custom message: %s was successfully added to your shopping cart.', $product->getName());
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($message);
```

Comment: I already found this example, which you have posted. The problem is - how I determine the options? Or - what is the difference between bundle_option and options?
The added products are all simple products. They have no option by themselfes. Or do I miss a point?
Also the weight of a bundled product is dynamic. Setting it would probably deactivate this functionality.